# Prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a matrix of $n\times n$ over a field $F$. Then a scalar $\lambda$ in $F$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

**Attempt:**

Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with an associated nonzero eigenvector $x$. Then either $Ax=\lambda x$ or $(A-\lambda I)x=0$. But from our results on invertible matrices, the equation $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ has a nonzero solution for $x$ if and only if the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, which is equivalent to saying $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: Your proof looks good.

Comment: "Then either $Ax = \lambda x$ or $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$" I'd change that phrasing to: "Then $Ax = \lambda x$, or equivalently $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$."